# Delete Duplicates From Text File Using Array

Tags: c#

This is my code but I'm not sure what to put in a certain area (see below) as I keep getting an error there. I am basically loading up a text file and then deleting any values that are repeated and then outputting the updated copy of the text file.

The text file looks like,

```
    5
    5
    3
    2
    2
    3
```

My code is

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Global Variable
    int[] Original;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Exit Application
    private void mnuExit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    //Load File
    private void mnuLoad_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code to Load the Numbers From a File
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();

        //Open the File Dialog and Check If A File Was Selected
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Open File to Read
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fd.OpenFile());
            int Records = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

            //Assign Array Sizes
            Original = new int[Records];

            //Go Through Text File              
            for (int i = 0; i < Records; i++)
            {
                Original[i] = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Store Original Array
        string Output = "Original \n";

        //Output Original Array
        for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length; i++)
        {
            Output = Output + Original[i] + "\n";
        }

        //Create TempArray
        int[] TempArray = new int[Original.Length];

        //Set TempArray Equal to Original Array
        for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length; i++)
        {
            TempArray[i] = Original[i];
        }

        //Current Index
        int Counter = 0;

        //Loop Through Entire Array
        for (int i = 0; i < TempArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < TempArray.Length; j++)
            {
                //Replace Duplicate Values With '-1'
                if (TempArray[i] == TempArray[j])
                {
                    TempArray[j] = -1;
                    Counter++;
                }
            }

        }

        //Set Size of Original Array
        Original = new int[Original.Length - Counter];

        //Counter = 0;
        //Remove -1 Values

//error begins here
for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < Original.Length; j++)
            {
                //Set Original Array Equal to TempArray For Values Not Equal To '-1'
                if (j != -1)
                {
                    Original[j] = TempArray[j];
                    //Counter++;
                }
            }
        }
 //error ends here
        //Final Output -- The New Array
        Output = Output + "Original Without Duplicates\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < Original.Length; i++)
        {
            Output = Output + Original[i] + "\n";
        }
        lblOutput.Text = Output;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see what error you are getting anywhere in the code, or what line its on

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: would Linq `Distinct` not do this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: `if(j != -1)` will always be `true` because `j` is initialized to `i+1` and `i` is initialized to 0 and both are only ever incremented.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your logic, but wer'e all lazy programmers. You could simply use `LINQ` in order to prevent duplication. Load the array as you did already and use the `Distinct` method somthing like this:

```
int[] newArray = Orginal.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Goodluck.

Comment: Hey, I understand I could be using this but the code I wrote is for a beginner's programming class and we haven't been taught LINQ yet. So my code has to be made up of arrays.